# Custom captcha Image not rendering when Integrated with sitecore

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to render custom captcha in asp.net mvc pages using captchamvc library from nuget as below.

```
@Html.Captcha("Refresh", "Enter_the_text_shown_in_image", 5, "Is required field.", false)
```

But instead of getting an image, this is what i get.

[image: custom captcha]

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

- check that **CaptchaMvc.xml** is deployed
  [image]
- make sure that image url generared by captchamvc *("/DefaultCaptcha/Generate?t=0784d3c58d09456b84b03552f8caea4e")* in not being processed by sitecore routes and mapped to wrong destination. You can add separate route for this url:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "CaptchaMvcRoute", url: "DefaultCaptcha/Generate", defaults: new { controller = "DefaultCaptcha", action = "Generate" });
```

- try to add to web.config:

```
<configuration>
   <location path="DefaultCaptcha/Generate">
       <system.web>
         <authorization>
           <allow users="?" />
         </authorization>
       </system.web>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

*Black square with red cross is an error bitmap of captchaMvc.*

Comment: where will i get CaptchaMvc.xml ?

Comment: if you install CaptchaMvc with nuget, just decompile any object from CaptchaMvc.dll to see where it is stored locally (in my case: c:\Users\sba\.nuget\packages\captchamvc.mvc5\1.5.0\lib\net45-full\CaptchaMvc.dll). Here you find CaptchaMvc.xml.